# How do you best manage database URL in firebase cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a dev database and a staging database and I want my firebase cloud functions to use whichever database is appropriate based on where it is deployed, is there a variable or something that I can reference for this so that I dont have to manually change the URL before every deploy to dev or staging environment?

```
var FirebaseDBUrlVar = 'some-url-to-firebase-dev';

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: FirebaseDBUrlVar,
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting version version 1.0 of the firebase-functions SDK, you can initialize the SDK with no arguments, and it will automatically pick up all the defaults for your environment:

```
admin.initializeApp()
```

If you need to add a service account to that, you can parse the defaults out of `process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG` and add the credential to it:

```
const serviceAccount = require('./service-account-credentials.json')
const adminConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG)
adminConfig.credential = admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
admin.initializeApp(adminConfig)
```